# Controlling tile overlays after orientation change in google maps android api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing an app using the google maps android api.  The app displays various tileoverlays that the user can turn on and off.  When I rotate my device the overlay remains in place but when I click the button to turn off my overlay my device acts as if the variable that controls my overlay is null.  How can I retain control over my tileoverlay under these circumstances.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    //mMap=null;
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // First incarnation of this activity.
        mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    } else  {
        // Reincarnated activity. The obtained map is the same map instance in the previous
        // activity life cycle. There is no need to reinitialize it.
        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
    }
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    setUpFieldsIfNeeded();
}
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
          // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
             mMap  = ((SupportMapFragment)   getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

          }
        }
      }
 private void setUpFieldsIfNeeded(){            

    if (fieldsOverlay == null) {
        TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
            @Override
            public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {


                //String s = String.format(Locale.US, CMAFieldsRequestFormat, zoom, x, y);  
                String s = String.format(Locale.US, cartoDBFieldsTile, zoom, x, y); 
                s =s.replace(" ", "%20");
                System.out.println(s);
                URL url = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL(s);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    throw new AssertionError(e);
                }
                return url;
            }
        };


         fieldsOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(
                 new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));
         fieldsOverlay.setVisible(false);
         fieldsOverlay.setZIndex(1);}

    }
```

TLDR: I'm using google maps with a tileOverlay named fieldsOverlay.  When I rotate my device the overlay itself is preserved but it is no longer connected to the variable fieldsOverlay.  What is the best way to fix this problem.

Thanks

edit:  I was able to get the app to appear to function the way I want by running mMap.clear then reinitializing my layer and setting the visibility to a savedInstanceState value when I reincarnate my activity, but this doesn't seem like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `SupportMapFragment.setRetainInstace` may seem like a quick way to achieve desired results, but it really is not.

First of all it causes a memory leak. Check out my [gmaps-api-issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5103) for discussion on it.

The issue you encounter there is quite normal. `TileOverlay` references you keep will not be retained when recreating `Activity`. Actually a new `Activity` object is created. Visual objects should be treated like normal Android `View`s: not kept when configuration changes. There was even a note on this in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/), but I cannot find it now.

If you don't use `setRetainInstance` you will not have problems with no references to your objects, because you have to create again on rotation.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly.  I had picked up that line of code from google's maps api demonstration projects and would like to warn others about it.